# how to change mysql concat code to pymysql code

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, pymysql

this is my mysql code

```
select ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{R_ICODE:"', R_ICODE, '", RANK:"',RANK,'"}')) list from RESULT where USER_ID='ehae065@daum.net' group by ID;
```

and this is my pymysql code

```
cursor.execute("ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{R_ICODE:"', R_ICODE, '", RANK:"', RANK, '"}')) list from RESULT where USER_ID='ehae065@daum.net' group by ID")
```

when i ran the pymysql code i got the syntex error so if someones knows the right way 
plz teach me 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you missed your `select` statement, 2nd is you need to `escape` your `double quotes`.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ID
    , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{R_ICODE:\"', R_ICODE, '\", RANK:"', RANK, '\"}')) list 
    FROM RESULT WHERE USER_ID='ehae065@daum.net' group by ID")
```

Comment: sorry but can i ask one more question i want to concat the ID and all GROUP_CONCAT contents so now i got the result 
4550,
"{R_ICODE:\"675\", RANK:\"1\"},{R_ICODE:\"924\", RANK:\"2\"},{R_ICODE:\"2304\",
RANK:\"3\"},{R_ICODE:\"760\", RANK:\"4\"},{R_ICODE:\"2302\", RANK:\"5\"}"

but i want to get the result

ID:4550{
{R_ICODE:\"675\", RANK:\"1\"},{R_ICODE:\"924\", RANK:\"2\"},{R_ICODE:\"2304\",
RANK:\"3\"},{R_ICODE:\"760\", RANK:\"4\"},{R_ICODE:\"2302\", RANK:\"5\"}}
so if you don't remind could you teach me how to change the query?!

Comment: try remove those slashes and lets see

Comment: ah! also i asked why slashes is show it i used flask api this functions..

Comment: replace slash with another double quote

Comment: 4550, "{R_ICODE:"675", RANK:"1"},{R_ICODE:"924", RANK:"2"},{R_ICODE:"2304", RANK:"3"},{R_ICODE:"760", RANK:"4"},{R_ICODE:"2302", RANK:"5"}" but i want to get the result 
ID:4550{ {R_ICODE:"675", RANK:"1"},{R_ICODE:"924", RANK:"2"},{R_ICODE:"2304", RANK:"3"},{R_ICODE:"760", RANK:"4"},{R_ICODE:"2302", RANK:"5"}}

Comment: appreciate first one is not all the json but second is all the json with ID

Comment: @hognkun, what do you mean?

Comment: this is my first result using your query 
4550, "{R_ICODE:"675", RANK:"1"},{R_ICODE:"924", RANK:"2"},{R_ICODE:"2304", RANK:"3"},{R_ICODE:"760", RANK:"4"},{R_ICODE:"2302", RANK:"5"}"

Comment: but i i want to get the result like this
ID:4550{ {R_ICODE:"675", RANK:"1"},{R_ICODE:"924", RANK:"2"},{R_ICODE:"2304", RANK:"3"},{R_ICODE:"760", RANK:"4"},{R_ICODE:"2302", RANK:"5"}}

Comment: so what should i change it